# Guaranteeing Quartz.NET Triggers only fire events once even with many instances

Tags: multithreading, triggers, quartz.net, appharbor

The title is kinda wacky, but I'm attempting to figure out a workaround for AppHarbor potentially firing off multiple instances of my background application. This application pushes critical events to my server on a basic schedule using Quartz.NET. However, *I cannot guarantee there is only one instance of my background application*, but I must have each event triggered as normal (essentially acting as one unit from the server's POV).

I had originally tried to solve this using locking and Redis, but I could not get that working well enough. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by having your job reschedule itself after each run. You don't specify what the schedule is but if it doesn't have to happen at the same time, then schedule the job with a trigger that only fires once. When the job has finished running, have it schedule itself again some time in the future. That way there is only one job in the store at any given time. You might have to get creative with how you load that initial job and handling errors, but as long as you can schedule only one job when you bootstrap, then you could possibly get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz.NET seems to have [built-in support for clustering](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-11). From the documentation:

> Only one node will fire the job for each firing. What I mean by that is, if the job has a repeating trigger that tells it to fire every 10 seconds, then at 12:00:00 exactly one node will run the job, and at 12:00:10 exactly one node will run the job, etc. It won't necessarily be the same node each time - it will more or less be random which node runs it. The load balancing mechanism is near-random for busy schedulers (lots of triggers) but favors the same node that just was just active for non-busy (e.g. one or two triggers) schedulers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it does not work with MongoDB which is my storage backend. I would prefer to keep the number of separate servers to a minimum if possible.